# accessing view from AsyncTask fails when view changed

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm building a module to capture screen shots of the application(rootview) while the user is using the app. I'm basically trying to create a video recording of the application usage. I decided to take the screenshots from AsyncTask since I can't block the main thread while I'm taking the screenshots. Here is the code I have so far

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button record = (Button) findViewById(R.id.record);

    final View content = findViewById(R.id.record).getRootView();
    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);       
    record.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mtask = (CaptureSnap) new CaptureSnap(content,getApplicationContext()).execute();
        }
    });

}
```

code in AsyncTask to take the screenshot

```
private Bitmap getScreen(int index){
    View content = view.findViewById(R.id.record).getRootView();
    try{
    if(content != null){
        Log.i(TAG, "taking screenshot "+index);
        Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
        return bitmap;
    }else
        return null;
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "Error for screenshot "+index);
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    while(indicator == 0){
        try{
            Bitmap screenshot = getScreen(0);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine unless I try to use the application while the screenshots being taken. I get the below error

```
    06-18 13:44:26.132: W/System.err(14096): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
06-18 13:44:26.164: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4888)
06-18 13:44:26.164: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:975)
06-18 13:44:26.164: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4125)
06-18 13:44:26.171: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10578)
06-18 13:44:26.171: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10533)
06-18 13:44:26.171: W/System.err(14096):    at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:4261)
06-18 13:44:26.171: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13710)
06-18 13:44:26.171: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2988)
06-18 13:44:26.171: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2858)
06-18 13:44:26.171: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13708)
06-18 13:44:26.171: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2988)
06-18 13:44:26.171: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2858)
06-18 13:44:26.171: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13829)
06-18 13:44:26.171: W/System.err(14096):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
06-18 13:44:26.171: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13710)
06-18 13:44:26.171: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2988)
06-18 13:44:26.171: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2858)
06-18 13:44:26.171: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13708)
06-18 13:44:26.171: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2988)
06-18 13:44:26.171: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2858)
06-18 13:44:26.179: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13829)
06-18 13:44:26.179: W/System.err(14096):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
06-18 13:44:26.179: W/System.err(14096):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2458)
06-18 13:44:26.187: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:13087)
06-18 13:44:26.187: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.View.getDrawingCache(View.java:12875)
06-18 13:44:26.187: W/System.err(14096):    at android.view.View.getDrawingCache(View.java:12840)
06-18 13:44:26.187: W/System.err(14096):    at com.example.recordit.CaptureSnap.getScreen(CaptureSnap.java:158)
```

Can someone assist me with this?

Comment: You can only access `View`s from the main thread. `doInBackground()` is running in a background thread...

Answer (score 0):

You need to call that from the UI thread, using a `Handler` to `post` the result back so that the UI thread can run it there instead

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved when I replaced AsyncTask with [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). I created a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) in the Acitivity which will post messages to handler which in turn takes the screenshots and serializes them to a file. Later on I use the files to encode them in to a video recording using JCodec. Thanks for the help.